Jetting a custom built motorcycle engine where to even start
I've bored up, stroked up, oversize valved, and change the carburetter on a Honda Tiger 200 cc Single cylinder engine. It is now 233 cc, 66 mm diameter piston and 68.2 mm stroke. I also have a cam with altered duration. The piston is CNC cut for a 10.5 to one compression ratio.  It's all from the same manufacturer here in Indonesia called Bintang racing team. And it's all a kit so all in theory plays well together.  I have a PE 28 carburettor and I've jetted it with every jet I have in a kit that came with it and it still runs like sh!t. I can get it to either idle OK or run OK for a bit but not both. Very often it runs OK when I first started up, but when it gets hot and/or I'm on an angle (down a hill clutch in) it dies completely. It over revs at idle after full throttle, legs when you give it a shot of gas. An absolutely hates running with a throttle, barely cracked going as slow as you can pass to church.  I've tried every jet in my kit basically in every combination and permutation, it has three needles. I've tried all of them. I've tried all needle positions all of this increasing one jet at a time and only making one change at a time. I've tried different air filters, no air filter.  Changed the manifold rubber that connects to the engine. I've changed the bit that bolt onto the engine: urethane, silicone, rubber, long short all of it
I've tuned lots of carburetors, I'm not a master or anything, but I've done it lots and always get it running pretty good as far as I can tell, but this thing is just killing me.
So how do I calculate what jets I should be using just theoretically, so I can have a ballpark to start in. I'm going mad. the displacement and stroke, and all that must be able to be plugged into an equation to give jetting size??????

If your displacement is 14% larger, why not start your jet size 14% larger? I think it would give you a good place to start. Short of running a wide band O2 on it to get it exactly right, this should get you near to where you need to be. You're going to need to do tuning on it, just like you would normally to get it right. This is probably the best you're going to do for a starting point.

I don't know what the original jetting was, but it's probably possible to find out. Also, I think I'll just buy a wideband O2 kit. It's not that expensive and I do think I might go injection in the future potentially.

@SVSavannah - A wide band is probably your best bet if you can afford one.

Just thought I'd tie up this post in case anyone is keeping track. In the end I went and got a wideband O2 kit, and I'm glad I did. It's been a really great learning experience. The stock carburetter on this engine (keeping in mind there is basically nothing stock at all left) had a 38 pilot and a 120 main. After extensive testing I have arrived at 38 pilot and 118 Main with the needle in position 4, and the needle is a J6ZG (but I have no idea what that means) it is the shortest of the three needles in the kit that came with my carburetor. It still has a tendency to go rich at about a 16th throttle and then riches out at full throttle after a few seconds (also note the carburetter has a power jet.  But to be honest, there's nowhere here that's not too scary to go full throttle for more than a couple of seconds, so I'll work on that but for all intent and purpose I think I'm there.
So I don't know how that works. Much bigger displacement, but still basically the same jetting.‍♂️  also, for anyone interested I was running way way way too rich on all my jets except I had a longer needle, and it was running incredibly lean when just barely cracked the throttle but wicked Rich everywhere else. So I think I cooked my valve doing short burst of acceleration and then backing right off when I saw a goat or a kid with a look in their eye like they wanted to commit suicide, and then backed off. Rinse and repeat.
